# Can't Pass Image Path From Decode File Bitmap (Xamarin Android) Path return Null Exception Error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to pass my image with intent in Xamarin Android with C#. In the first activity, I am using `BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(uri_path);`for decode my image path into bitmap file. I also set that bitmap picture with `imgView.SetImageBitmap(BitMap);` then, I pass that URI path in my button click which is the button will reference the picture to the next activity using `intent.PutExtra("path", mCurrentPhotoPath);`. In the next activity, I want to get the passing path value from the first activity.

```
string path = intent.GetStringExtra("path");

            if (path != null)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(path);
                m_imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Your picture empty!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
```

But, I get an error with a null exception error. The path return null and the program is crashing. Please help me! I feel stuck after few hours. Any help?
Here's my full code :

first activity - my onActivityResult

```
private Button btnContinue, btnCapture;
        private ImageView imgView;
        public Bitmap BitMap;
        private Android.Net.Uri filePath;
        private const int c_TAKE_IMAGE_REQUSET = 72;
        private ProgressBar progressBar;
        public String mCurrentPhotoPath = null;

public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == c_TAKE_IMAGE_REQUSET &&
        resultCode == (int)Result.Ok &&
        data != null)
    {
        filePath = data.Data;
        //String mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        try
        {
            mCurrentPhotoPath = GetRealPathFromURI(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Failed for some reason.
        }

        try
        {
            BitMap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
            imgView.SetImageBitmap(BitMap);
            BitMap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Image path == " + mCurrentPhotoPath);
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath); // decode the path into bitmap 
        imgView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}

private string GetRealPathFromURI(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        string doc_id = "";
        using (var c1 = this.View.Context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null))
        {
            c1.MoveToFirst();
            string document_id = c1.GetString(0);
            doc_id = document_id.Substring(document_id.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        }

        string path = null;

        // The projection contains the columns we want to return in our query.
        string selection = Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " =? ";
        using (var cursor = this.View.Context.ContentResolver.Query(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, null, selection, new string[] { doc_id }, null))
        {
            if (cursor == null) return path;
            var columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
            cursor.MoveToFirst();
            path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

second activity - onCreate
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Upload);

        string path = intent.GetStringExtra("path");

        if (path != null)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(path);
            m_imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Your picture empty!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }

        m_upload.Click += M_upload_Click;

    }
```

EDIT: I Put my put string extra in my button. The button is Button Continue which is a reference to the next activity

```
private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Busy();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(UploadActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("path", mCurrentPhotoPath);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you are calling `PutExtra`

Comment: Edit: I put my PutExtra on my button. Please check my edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this only happens after you've taken a picture,because `filePath = data.Data;` return `null`,if you choose a picture from photos,it will return its `uri`.

So you could try to use other methods,you could passing the `byte[]` data of the bitmap after you take a picture :

```
public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == c_TAKE_IMAGE_REQUSET &&
            resultCode == (int)Result.Ok &&
            data != null)
        {

            try
            {
                mBitMap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
                imgView.SetImageBitmap(mBitMap);
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    mBitMap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
                    bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
                }
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

then you could pass the `bitmapData` :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(UploadActivity));
intent.PutExtra("img", bitmapData);
StartActivity(intent);
```

show it in new activity :

```
byte[] bitmapbyte = Intent.GetByteArrayExtra("img");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bitmapbyte, 0, bitmapbyte.Length);
m_imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**Update**:

if you want to use file path,you could do like this:

```
private Java.IO.File outputImage;
private Android.Net.Uri photoUri;   // the camera takes a photo and returns the image path    

//Create a file object to store the image after the photo is taken, which is also the photo path after the photo is taken successfully
Java.IO.File outputImage = new Java.IO.File(xxx,xxx);
//determine the current Android version
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
    {
      photoUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this, "xxxxx", outputImage);
    }
else
    {
      photoUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(outputImage);
    }

 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
 intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, photoUri);
 StartActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_IMAGE_REQUSET);
```

then you could use `photoUri`.

And on some devices you could use below method to save the picture and get the path.

```
filePath = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage(Activity.ContentResolver, mBitMap, null, null));
```

**Note**:

[FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) is used in Android 7.0 and above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, seriously I can't pass my path and then decode the path into bitmap? Some people say that It's not good to pass the byte because It takes a memory of your phone. How about `mbitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);` ? If I don't compress the bitmap, is it okay?

Comment: @Anastasia It is best to compress, because sometimes the bitamp will be too large to cause oom,and if you want to use path,you could define a file path first,and then set it as a output path.I will give you an update

Comment: Ah, I see, well, in my opinion, I don't think if we compress the bitmap then it would be the best technique. I read some articles on google that, if we compress the bitmap then the bitmap will lose its image detail. So, the quality of the image would be bad. But, thanks for your information! I will try to define a file path first!

Comment: @Anastasia I have updated above,you could refer it,not the complete codes

Comment: Alright, I see! I will try it. I want to ask, in the part xxx, xxx in  `new Java.IO.File(xxx, xxx);` what should I put? and also xxx in `photoUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this, "xxxxx", outputImage);` is my picture name?

Comment: @Anastasia Not all,you could check the IntelliSense of the method.

Comment: @Anastasia you could try the `filePath = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage(Activity.ContentResolver, mBitMap, null, null));` first.

Comment: put it below your bitmap

Comment: inside the callback of take picture

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help! It helps me a lot! Now, I get my path and I can pass the path and decode the path into a bitmap. God Bless you, man! I will click accept your answer :D

Comment: Oh ya, sorry if I ask you again. I just want to know. Why if I use the filePath = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage(Activity.ContentResolver, mBitMap, null, null)); my image resolution in the first activity and the next activity is different from gallery. When in gallery, the image from both activity still has good resolution

Comment: use `MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage(Activity.ContentResolver, mBitMap, null, null);`  ,it will do a photo save manually, and it will generate a thumbnail image and return to you, so it looks a little different from the original image in the gallery